# Making Dot function python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to make a dot function that is var.function() that changes var? I realise that i can do:

```
class Myclass:
   def function(x):
      return 2
Myclass.function(1):
```

But i want to change it like the default python function.

```
def function(x):
   return(3)
x=1
x.function()
print(x)
```

and it returns

```
>>> 3
```

Comment: You know, that everything in python is object, right? Your second code snippet will raise `AttributeError`. and if not - then you call existing method of a built-in type, not user defined function.

Comment: Do you want to be able to call it for `x` being an `int`, or was that just a bad example? You can't add properties and methods to built-in types. Perhaps you rather want to be able to write `x = MyClass(); x.function()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
class Myclass:
  def __init__(self, num):
    self.num = num
  
  def function(self):
    self.num += 1

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.num)

x = Myclass(3)
x.function()
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is weird usage. I suggest you to create custom class to do that, try using @property inside it if you don't want to call function in code.